# Trying to understand Auto reconnect WIFI method

Tags: networking, wifi, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I found this method of reconnecting the WIFI dongle from [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4120/how-to-automatically-reconnect-wifi). But, I want to be clear on how it works, before I try and implement it.

> 1. Go to `/etc/ifplugd/action.d/` and rename the `ifupdown` file to
>      `ifupdown.original`.
> 2. Then do: `cp /etc/wpa_supplicant/ifupdown.sh ./ifupdown`.
> 3. Finally: `sudo reboot`

1. When is `/etc/ifplugd/action.d/ifupdown` called ?
2. What does the script `/etc/wpa_supplicant/ifupdown.sh` essentially do in laymens terms, it looks pretty complex to me; and when is it called too.
3. Could doing steps 1 to 3 cause any other unforeseen problems that would prevent my WIFI from working? I'm trying to implement this on a Raspberry PI, via SSH, without a keyboard and monitor in a hard to reach location.

I tried to Google various bits, but got a bit lost!

Answer (score 1):

ifplugd is meant to detect remove or reconnection of an ethernet connector.  The associated directory /etc/ifplugd/action.d/ hosts scripts that get called when, for example, the connector is plugged in (or removed).

Step 2 in your process would cause the wpa connection to be (re)negotiateed when the connector is inserted (or removed), and it assumes the connection is WPA.  The rename/copy process you describe would disable any pre-existing processing done in the pre-existing ifupdown script, which might be negligible or not.  You might consider simply calling the /etc/wpa_supplicant/ifupdown.sh by adding that to the existing ifupdown script (at the end, for example), but it depends on understand what is already in the existing script (which is often simple).

If you merely want to renegotiate the wifi connection if or when it drops, instead of handling physical disconnection of the connector, you might consider using this:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dweeber/WiFi_Check/master/WiFi_Check

That script is robust, mostly harmless, and should do the trick robustly.

Answer (score 1):

## Short version

1. Answered by dudek already; that directory is used for scripts that tell your system how to handle things getting pluged in to it or un-pluged from it.
2. See "Long version" for attempts at explaining how I've come to understand the script in question. Basicly after running some checks and loading some externall functions it checks if it should run either the `start` sequence of commands, or `stop`, or error out and exit.
3. Oh yeah, it very well could lock you out of remote access if ya touch the networking configs in a way that the RPi doesn't much like. I've touched my networking configs so roughly in the past on my RPi that it's been simpler to start from a fresh install. Be cairful and consider moving the RPi temperaroly to a location that is easire to login to localy.

## Long version

Looking through this file on my RPi it seems well commented and it doesn't use to many external function calls. But you've asked for laymens terms so I'll do my best to explain how I go about coming to understand these kinds of scripts, though, as it looks like you're a RPi user like me (headless remote server setup) ya might wana check what I've alread writen over on the [RPi StackExchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/34440/8651) for auto-reconection to hidden WiFi networks as it may have other tricks useful to your server requirements.

To help aid in answering your questions here's a bit of shell scripting syntax expaination;

In shell `~.sh` scripts it is *common* to find functions defined like so;

```
function_name () {
    echo "doing stuff for function_name"
}
```

and then called via `function_name` latter on in the script, sometimes within other functions. Functions, script files and if statments are just lists of commands to run. In the case of functions the stuff between `{` and `}` are run and in the case of `if` statments the stuff between `then` and `fi` are run and in instences where `else` or `elif` are used within `if` statments conditionally.

For the file we're disecting there are functions named `do_start`, `do_stop` and some functions defined in other files... "What files are these other functions definded?" or "How do I find if script a loads functions from file b?" are two questions we'll have to answer first.

Around line `48` in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/ifdown.sh` there's a commented line (ie line beguining with `#` simble; these are ignored by script intrupriter... mostly) with `source functions` coventently labbling the next few lines' intended perpos~

```
# source functions
if [ -f /etc/wpa_supplicant/functions.sh ]; then
    . /etc/wpa_supplicant/functions.sh
else
    exit
fi
```

Note this is a good example of scripting behaviour; checking if a file is there before assuming that it is.

The first bit `if [ -f` is checking for a file under the defined file path. And if present `then` load contents of file via `source` (short-hand of `source` command is `.` but I avoid using it in my scripts because it can be missintuprated by `cp` and other commands but digress I have) the file defined by the path. Next is an `else` check that if that file was not found `exit 0` exit with status `0` the script. Then the `if` stetment ends with `fi` to close actions to take if the first statment didn't pass. Or in other words if /etc/wpa_supplicant/functions.sh does **not** exsist then exit, otherwise load those functions and continue processing. This kind of duble-checking if a value or file is present is something you'll see repeated throughout the script in question as well as other scripts, the `-f` checks for files, `-n` checks string length, `-x` checks not only if a file is there but also if user running the script has executable permissions for the file defined, `-s`  checks if a file is empty, `-n` checks if string is not empty or `null` value, and `=` compares strings (or values) in `if` statments. Something else you'll see in shell and bash scripts on Linux with `if` statments `elif` but that's for another day. Within this script are other *tricks* used in addition to `if` statments such as `||` "or", `&&` "and", and `!` "not" operators, such as on line `55`~

```
# quit if executables are not installed
if [ ! -x "$WPA_SUP_BIN" ] || [ ! -x "$WPA_CLI_BIN" ]; then
    exit 0
fi
```

~ which simply put states, if file defined by `$WPA_SUP_BIN` is **not** executable or the file defined by `$WPA_CLI_BIN` is **not** executable then exit with status `0` without processing further. These can look complex at first but reading them out loud in a more human syntax can help when first learning, for the simple ones, and adding comments with `#` for complex ones is really helpful when learning or coming back to the subject latter.

The file that is sourced internally should also be inspected if unsure as to what something called within the `ifupdown.sh` file. I'd suggest `nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/functions.sh` and then using `^w` or `Ctrl+w` to search around for the function's name that you wish to know more about. Because between what ever task calls this script and the contence of `functions.sh` most of the puzzel peces will be found.

Now things get to looing a bit differant 'round line `135` where a `case` statment is started, these kinds of statments have a sertain structure we can use to help decode opearations.

```
case $some_variable in
    start)
         echo "The word [start] was detected in \$some_variable"
    ;;
    stop)
         echo "The word [stop] was detected in \$some_variable"
    ;;
    *)
         echo "The word [$some_variable] was detected in \$some_variable but not understood"
    ;;
esac
```

In the above example as with other `case` statments we're essentially searching the contents of `$some_variable` for the key words defiened, ie `start` or `stop` and if the key word is found then issue commands found between trailling `)` and preseading `;;` that acts to sepperate differant actions to take for various key words found. Note in some scripts you may find these `case` statments within `for` loops but that too is for another day.

In the case of the `case` statements within `ifupdown.sh` script we're first matching the `start` or `stop` status within `$MODE` variable and using `$PHASE` value to match if `pre-up` or `post-up` sequence of command should be called **or** if the `pre-down` or `post-down` sequence of commands should be called instead. If niether `start` nor `stop` where detected then an error is logged, printed and script is exited with status `1` an error.