# Wi-Fi drops, it's really complicated to autoreconnect? Raspberry Pi with Octopi/Octoprint

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I loaded up Octopi, the distro version of [Octoprint](http://octoprint.org/download/) to a Raspberry Pi B+.  I finally got things working and a few things printed, and then all of a sudden I'm greeted with a message in the interface saying that it had been disconnected, and the LED on the [Wi-Pi](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BDW6D7I) was out.

I could not reconnect, or find it in the connected devices of my router, so I connected some peripherals and lo and behold, the Wi-Fi had dropped.  I was able to reconnect by removing the Wi-Pi and plugging it back in.

Doing a search on the net yielded me headache/nauseating results about cron jobs, modifying scripts, or installing Wi-Fi managers.  However, those articles and questions are all 1 - 3 years old.

- [How to automatically reconnect WiFi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4120/how-to-automatically-reconnect-wifi)
- [WiFi disconnects after period of time on Raspberry Pi, doesn't reconnect](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27475/wifi-disconnects-after-period-of-time-on-raspberry-pi-doesnt-reconnect)
- [WIFI Drops Out](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=31456&p=276102)
- [Wifi Reconnect on drop](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=16054&sid=1d900f33d410ab12473f171f553b2b2f&start=25)
- [Trying to understand Auto reconnect WIFI method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139884/trying-to-understand-auto-reconnect-wifi-method)

Apparently the newest version of the Octopi distro (0.12, the one that I'm using) does something different with the Wi-Fi management, so you can only get it to connect by modifying `octopi-network.txt` and putting in the SSID and password.

I've got a few closely related questions:

1. Can Raspbian/Debian not automatically reconnect itself to a network?
2. How is that, or under what circumstances is that, a good idea?
3. Do you still have to fiddle with Raspbian to get it to auto-reconnect?
4. What would be some things to look for in a Wi-Fi management suite in Linux?  I am familiar with Windows and over there, that sort of thing is part of the OS and/or driver package.
5. Why did this question go unanswered? [Trying to understand Auto reconnect WIFI method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139884/trying-to-understand-auto-reconnect-wifi-method)

Comment: I don't know the Octoprint neither the Wi-Pi. But I have a Raspberry Pi 2 and a WiFi dongle and although I'm using mostly the Ethernet port, I haven't had any problems with Wifi disconnections. Which driver is being used (check dmesg or `lsusb -v`)? Which kernel are you running (`uname -a`)? Are you in an apartment with many Wifi around or there isn't much interferences where you're? Are your Raspberry Pi far away from your Wifi access point (e.g. router)? Basically I'm trying to see if the disconnections are a driver or more environment problem.